# How to make prepend option disabled laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

There is dropdown and it's first option is default selected.

Controller :

```
$position = JobPosition::all()->pluck('position','id');
$position->prepend('Position you are applying for', '');
return view($layout.'.careers')->with(['page'=>$page,'careers' => $careers,'position' => $position]);
```

View :

```
{!! Form::select('job_position_id', $position, null, array('class' => 'select-design') )!!}
```

how can i make "Position you are applying for" a disabled option ?

Comment: $('select.position option:first').attr('disabled', true); this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{!! Form::select('job_position_id', $position, null, array('class' => 'select-design') )!!}
```

Third argument is for default selection. Find more info on [creating a select box field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field)